# betting and probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I got problem answering this puzzle, would really appreciate your help. It goes like this:

> We are racing, and can at any time signal to the other that we would
>   like to double our bet. We've put down 100 to start and during the
>   race I signal to you I want to double the bet, What is the minimum
>   probability of winning for you to accept to continue?

Comment: I think this has to do with sunk costs, the 100 at the start has no influence.

Comment: Looking at estimated return fro a single game, You can accept any bet where your winning probability exceeds your share in the pot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, by declining, the player immediately loses. Then the value of declining is $-100$

The expected value of accepting is (where $p$ is the probability of winning) $200p-(1-p)200$.

$200p-(1-p)200\geq-100$

$p\geq\frac{1}{4}$

If, on the other hand, by declining, the race continues at the current stakes, then we have:

$p\geq\frac{1}{2}$